# accessing dictionary with classes

Tags: python

I am learning OOP with python.
I want to implement something like to display:
`firstName`, `lastName` of a person with address as dictionary like, `'state': someState, 'city': someCity`

I've done:

```
class data:
    def __init__(self, firstName, lastName, **address):
        self.firstName = firstName
        self.lastName = lastName
        self.address = {
            "state": self.state,
            "city" : self.city
        }
```

When I did:

```
>>> d = data("a", "b", 'state' : "stat", 'city' : "ci")
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> d = data("a", "b", 'state'="stat", 'city'="ci")
SyntaxError: keyword can't be an expression
```

Is there mistake with my code or the syntax of accessing dictionary is mistake. I can not figure it out.

Comment: @nischalinn: Read the tutorial.  This is a real basic question about Python's syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should just define a new dict as the argument to your constructor and then copy it in the constructor like this.

```
class Data:
    def __init__(self, firstName, lastName, address):
        self.firstName = firstName
        self.lastName = lastName
        self.address = dict(address)

data = Data("first", "last", dict(state="pa", city="pittsburgh"))
```

Answer (score 2):

In your constructor you are using `:` that is incorect, kwargs should be name=val.  Also you can not to `self.state` or `self.city` because you have not set them yet.  You need to go to the kwargs dictionary and pull them out.  any reason you want to do **address?

```
class data:
    def __init__(self, firstName, lastName, **address):
        self.firstName = firstName
        self.lastName = lastName
        self.address = {
             "state": address.get('state', ''),
             "city" : address.get('city', ''),

        }
```

There really is no reason to do the adress the way you specified... I would suggest doing state/city as an explicit kwargs.

```
class data:
    def __init__(self, firstName, lastName, state='', city=''):
        self.firstName = firstName
        self.lastName = lastName
        self.address = {
             "state": state,
             "city" : city,

        }
```

---

```
d = data("a", "b", state="stat", city="ci")
```

Comment: `d = data("a", "b", 'state="stat", city="ci")`, are we missing another `'`?... Your `'state` didn't close with `'`?

Comment: When trying to edit answer, i actually edited someone else's(and made it darn good)...  can't really undo it.. so my apologizes @David Halter

Answer (score 0):

You have to use it like this:

```
d = data("a", "b", state="stat", city="ci")
```

The input has to be a name, not a string. Therefore it is impossible to input something like `city-zip`. Because it contains a dash (which is a minus in python).

Answer (score 0):

You have to call it like this

```
d = data("a", "b", state="stat", city="ci")
```

Also there is no such variable as `self.state` or `self.city` until you assign them.

eg.

```
self.state = address['state']
self.city = address['city']
```